# Access Android Content Provider Data via Lua Script

Tags: lua, android-ndk, android-contentprovider, luabind

I am aware that one could query Content providers for the data using
Content Provider Class using Android based API's.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html

However is there any library which allows access to this data by
making Native Calls (Lua Script) e.x Say if I need to read the contact
information about a person in Contact List of a mobile device, by
making calls in Lua Script, Is it possible? Is there any library with
Lua like syntax which could read data natively?

If not what is the best way to accomplish the above task? So far I
have been successful to read the SQLite3 database local to the
application using LuaSQL library. Now I want to read the data from
Content Provider some way using Lua.

All your help is appreciated. Thanks.